# Read POST request with AjaxMethod

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need read POST request in my page. I using .net 2.0, higher version is not possible, and i try build page with AjaxPro. When i send request in JS to my destination, i cannot read request using `Request.Form`, `Page.Request` or other. Here is my code

```
public class Ajax : System.Web.UI.Page{

    [AjaxMethod]
    public string getString(){

        //here i would like read POST request

        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Request.QueryString["varname"];`?

Comment: Do you get any parameters to that method?

Comment: Yes, i try and doesn't work, return error with System.Web.HttpException

Comment: Important part is that i using application/json as Content Type.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to read the data from the InputStream. One such [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110016/what-is-request-inputstream-and-when-to-use-it) has more details on this. Also, you can reset the stream and then read the contents like the following

```
request.InputStream.Position = 0;
// read the data
```

Comment: If i try read Request.InputStream, anything from them, i receive error with System.Web.HttpException. I think, if i missing some important part of system services in using or function declaration.

Comment: can you please post the exception details so that we can analyze the exception

Comment: unfortunately i can't, this is all what i see in network request, i'm newbie in asp.net, only if there any error log