# Why do I have to read the inputStream in the Global.asax Application_BeginRequest method passing to the controler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, inputstream

I have a large body of JSON being sent to an endpoint of a .NET MVC app.  The endpoint will always successfully execute the first time.  The next time I use the endpoint, I get:

> System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x800703E5. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703E5): Overlapped I/O operation is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E5)

If I reset IIS, the problem goes away for only 1 request.  If I READ the inputStream in the Global.Asax.cs file, the problem goes away.

Here's the method signature in the controller:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(int personId, int visitId, int documentId, [FromBody]StoredDocumentDetails value, string locale = null)
```

Here's the Global.asax.cs method:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var application = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (application != null && application.Context != null)
        {
            application.Context.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        }
        if (Log.IsDebugEnabled() && application != null)
        {

            var requestBytes = new byte[application.Request.InputStream.Length];
            var currentPosition = application.Request.InputStream.Position;
            application.Request.InputStream.Read(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);
            application.Request.InputStream.Position = currentPosition;
            var requestBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBytes);
            Log.DebugFormat("Incoming Request Body: {0}", requestBody);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the "using" block for application.Request.InputStream? The error basically means the input stream from the first call is still open when you make the second call. If you use the using block, then the clean up for the first request should happen.

Comment: I only added the inputStream logging after I started receiving the error.  Is there any way to ensure the inputStream is read/closed properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110016/what-is-request-inputstream-and-when-to-use-it describes broader scope of when this should be used so you can determine if you actually need to be using the request stream. https://gist.github.com/leggetter/769688 describes what I was talking about the "using" block that will handle the clean up and rid you of that I/O error.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.  I don't want to use the inputStream.  I find that if I do NOT read the inputStream before passing control, the application fails because the body of the request does not make it to the controller's method.

Comment: ah I see, I think I misunderstood your question. Thanks for clarifying. This Application_BeginRequest method would run before every api request, removing the "Server" response header, correct? So why does not removing that particular header in the response cause it not to hit your endpoint? It would make much more sense if you were altering the request. Have you tried using Postman or Fiddler to try to directly hit the api endpoint?